# Throwing error while calling script from another script

Tags: shell

I have script test.sh with below command and when I run ./test.sh its working fine.But When I call test.sh from another script it throws error

```
cat main.sh
 sh test.sh
```

When I ran ./main.sh

> line 163: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   line 163:`    comm -13 <( sort $input_path/From_mount.txt ) <( sort 
>   $input_path/To_mount.txt ) |  sed -e "s/$/\|/g" > 
>   $input_path/To_new_mount.txt'

test.sh

```
comm -13 <( sort $input_path/From_mount.txt ) <( sort $input_path/To_mount.txt ) |  sed -e "s/$/\|/g" > $input_path/To_new_mount.txt
```

Please help !!!

---

any way this works for me

```
cat $input_path/From_mount.txt | sort > $input_path/fr_sort.txt
cat $input_path/To_mount.txt | sort > $input_path/to_sort.txt
comm -13 $input_path/fr_sort.txt $input_path/to_sort.txt |  sed -e "s/$/\|/g" > $input_path/To_new_mount.txt
```

But still want to know why `test.sh` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need some modification in your script. First of all always add this `#!/bin/bash` line at the top of your shell script. This line indicate in which shell you want to execute your script. Here I have mentioned `bash` hence your below script will run in `bash` shell. The reason is that every shell have different syntax for shell command especially for `(`, `if` condition, `while` loop etc. So add this line at the top of both your `test.sh` file as well as `main.sh` file. Also in your `main.sh` remove `sh` and just add `./test.sh`. If possible always use full path.